# Persiste @ManyToOne NULL

Tags: jpa

Tenho uma classe Usuario e outra Contato a qual possuem um relacionamento entre as mesmas. Esta tudo funcionando corretamente a questão que eu preciso que somente seja gravado um contato se houver algum atributo de contato preenchido, mas se o usuário preencher somente os atributos obrigatórios de usuário e descartar o preenchimento de contato preciso que na tabela usuário fique com NULL e não gerando um Contato apenas com seu ID.
Mapeamento do relacionamento.

```
@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "contact_id")
private Contato contato;
```

Comment: Quando eu chamo a exibição da tela eu preciso do:
usuario.setContato(new Contato());
caso não faça ele apresenta erro de NULL ao gravar e não efetuar a gravação.
Como eu faço este New ele volta e preenche o BD com o ID apenas do contato, sendo que na tela o usuário não preencheu nada.